# Unity3D object to swift project

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

How do I integrate the unity3d rendered object to my swift project? . i am trying to integrate the 3D model in a UIView and detect the touched part . i could do it in unity3D . Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Unity3D is not meant to be used for export of models or scenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is mostly used to render interactive 2D/3D scene and not to export rendered mesh.
After some digging, I found [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportFBX.html) which explains how to export an element of the scene into FBX. Once the mesh exported, you could import it into your swift project.

However, since Unity can compile your projet to most platform including iOS and OSX, I don't see why you have a Unity project on one hand and a swift project on the other hand.
For Unity work on iOS or OSX, you need to have it installed on a mac with XCode installed (Here the [official tutorial](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-GettingStarted.html)) and in my opinion, you should merge your swift project with your Unity project.

With Unity, you can detect touch with the following code (see more examples [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html))

```
void Update() {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            // Get movement of the finger since last frame
            Vector2 position = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

        }
```

Once you have your touch position, you should cast a Ray and check if it intersect with your object

Here is how to cast a Ray from the touch position

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
```